# Allowed memory size of 2097152000 bytes exhausted SQL server Php ODBC connect

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, memory, odbc

[image]

i'm trying to fetch the details from database(MS Sql).I can get the datils from small amount of data but i can't get large amount of data.kindy check the image for the error i have faced.I have increased memory limit in php.ini(16M to 2000M).still i can't get

Comment: Code. Post code, not a screenshot of the error.

Comment: Controller                                                                                                     public function test(){
  $userdetails =  $this->Member_model->get();
  print_r($userdetails);
 }

Comment: Model :       function get(){
  $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('picmeusers3');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result_array();
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
 }

Comment: Call me crazy, but  should your query look more like this: `function get()
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('picmeusers3')->get();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    return false;
}`

Comment: Crazy still i'm getting same error.it's not a coding problem.memory problem

Comment: The problem is with the code, not the memory, somewhere some thing's leaking. For starters, place a `LIMIT` on the query and don't select all the fields. See where that takes you.

Comment: Alright. Update your question with ALL the code in question, not just the query and no screenshots. You want help, learn how to post a proper question. I don't like guessing.

Comment: And according to [CI documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html) the way you're doing the query is wrong.

Comment: @sarathjay Instead of putting full function code in comments you should just re edit your question by clicking on the edit button below tags.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem some days ago. It is the problem of our code where there may be a loop which is running indefinitely. Please check your code and create test case for it. May be there is a situation where loop does not break and run indefinitely. 
In this case the memory does not allow to execute the code.

Comment: Boss small amount of data came but large data did not come because memory limit problem

Comment: No it is not because of data coming... There is a loop which does not break and running infinitely. Thats why problem occurs.